# Enable editing ListBox items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I'm writing a tag control, based on the listbox.

It is displaying the ListBox items using following template:

```
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
              <DataTemplate>
                <local:TagControl Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Remove="RemoveItem" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

I've noticed that when I update TagControl's text, the original item in the ListBox does not get updated. I'm using `ObservableCollection<string>` as items source.

TagControl implements INotifyPropertyChanged and calls the event.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you fire the PropertyChanged event after set the TagControl's text?

Comment: what are you actualy trying to bind to - that's not enough code.

Comment: @Miklos: yes,I'm firing PropertyChanged.

Comment: @NSGaga: what part of the code would you like to see?

Comment: the relevant bits - your view models, TagControl - to be able to see how things flow from XAML to MVVM and back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your problem and can offer a solution.  The `ObservableCollection<string>` is enumerated using IEnumerable which is read-only.

If you replace the `ObservableCollection<string>` with `ObservableCollection<DataItem>` where

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Name{get;set;} 
}
```

and then bind to Name in your DataTemplate, the enumerated DataItem is read-only, but the Name property is read-write and will be updated when you edit the text in the list item.